# connectionstring in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, string, connection

I am kind of new to programming,  i am doing a vb.net  database project in which i am using access database as my backend database. I am using visual studio 2010.

I have used a folder browser dialog to  get the directory where my access .accdb file is. I have used a string to get the  the strings together to form a connectionstring. My problem is how can i make the program to wait for me to select a location  to complete the connectionstring? how can i prevent the program from looking up the connectionstring in "my settings" tab in my  project page....

Also using add datasource wizard,when deployed gives error that db file is not found in the displayed location, and if i check that location i see two files and the db is present in one file but the displayed location is other file.

```
Private Sub SettingToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SettingToolStripMenuItem.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Connectstring = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath()

    connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & Connectstring & "\QuestionPool.accdb;"

    connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionstring) 'is not needed. garbage code.

    writer = New StreamWriter("Connectionstring.connection")
    writer.WriteLine(connectionstring)
    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

also I can't get the

```
connection = new oledbconnection(connectionstring)
```

to work.

I have to include home. connectionstring in the dataset.designer.vb to get the connection work.

Also how do I add the connection string variable to my.settings tab?

Comment: You generally store connection strings in the web.config and then reference them in your code behind with `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString")` or `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("myConnectionString")` classes. Connection Strings, as the name suggests, are just strings that get fed through as part of the connection to the db (along with the command, connection and the adapter). You also need to import `System.Data.OleDb` as well.